# How do I extend an action bar and a listview in the same activity?

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement an action bar in my app.  I'm trying to do this without losing support for older Android versions using this sample app as my inspiration...

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html

The problem I face is that the sample extends ActionBarActivity in the main page.  My app's page extends ListActivity.  I know you can't extend both in the same activity, but I'm not really sure how to implement the ActionBarActivity into my existing ListActivity...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need not to extend any of these as the action bar and the list view can be used by making the objects of them.
But if you wanna use the code of your action bar example as it is, extend that and make the object of ListView in your activity and do a little tweaks like replacing the overridden methods provided by the ListActivity.